# How to store and expand the variable in a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the size of a **S3 Folder** and store it in a **INFLUXDB**

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash -x
FILESIZE=$(mktemp)
 s3cmd du -r "s3://path1/path2/" | awk '{print $1}' >> "$FILESIZE"
cat "$FILESIZE"

echo curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=S3check&precision=s" --data-binary "ecmwftrack,bucketpath=ecmwf-archive/daily size='$FILESIZE'"
```

Below is my output
[image]

Output of $FILESIZE **46473946436**

But when i used **$FILESIZE** in a **CURL** command am not getting the value...
**FILESIZE is coming as a output...**

How can i make the value of $FILESIZE to appear in output

Comment: Do you want to post the file or the data in the file?

Comment: @VigneshSP No i just want to post the output of the file..i.e 46473946436

Comment: Do you have single quotes inside double ones (as your code says – I think that should work) or double ones inside single ones (as your screenshot says) in the last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the data, can you try the below?

```
#!/bin/bash -x
FILESIZE=$(mktemp)
 s3cmd du -r "s3://path1/path2/" | awk '{print $1}' >> "$FILESIZE"
cat "$FILESIZE"

echo curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=S3check&precision=s" --data-binary "ecmwftrack,bucketpath=ecmwf-archive/daily size=$(cat $FILESIZE)"
```

Comment: it works like a charm

Comment: Thank u for helping me